# WebPack 2: node.global and resolve.extensions empty extension configuration fields issue

Tags: webpack

I'm receiving this messages according to my old 2.1.0-beta.22 webpack configuration file. I need som esuggestions according to how to change that:

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.node.global should be a boolean.
 - configuration.resolve.extensions[0] should not be empty.
```

Currently:

```
resolve: {

  extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.json'],
  modules: [helpers.root('src'), 'node_modules'],

},
```

And

```
node: {
  global: 'window',
}
```

These are my config files:

- [webpack.common.js](https://gist.github.com/jeusdi/134e19006a6f8da06bf4123c35d8a8a7)
- [webpack.dev.js](https://gist.github.com/jeusdi/365e8cc433ef629d6246776dce0e3092)
- [webpack.prod.js](https://gist.github.com/jeusdi/919e6228b753cbe67f72edfd613a8c99)

Comment: `extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.json']` erase the '' => `extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json']`, in version 2 it's not necesary

Answer (score 0):

Try using '*' for instead of ''

```
resolve: { extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']},
```

It works in rc.7 - [details here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions)